# How to differentiate parameters from local variables

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I'm analysing source codes with Sonar API and one of my rules is visiting identifiers.

I need to differentiate between a local variable and a parameter, but I couldn't find a simple way to do it. I thought about getting the identifier's parent until Kind.METHOD or Kind.CONSTRUCTOR is found and get it's list of parameters to match with the identifier.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple approaches are possible (mainly relying on semantic API), but the easiest one would be to make your rule visit METHOD (MethodTree) as well as IDENTIFIER.

- When entering a method, store the symbols associated to each of its arguments.
- When visiting identifiers, then, check that the associated symbol is not part of the already know arguments.

Note that using the semantic API, you will also be able to get the owner of the identifier, but for both parameters and local variables, it will be the method. Consequently, you will need additional steps to differentiate both cases (you may need then to look at where is the declaration of the symbol in the syntax tree, and if the parent tree is an argument list...)